# How can I setup a props-based animate transition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-router

So I'm really noobish with VueJS but I have experience with React... which doesn't help.

My initial goal is to make 4 pages available, and, since they have an 'order', the transition classname would change accordingly.

Here is my `main.js` file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Landing from "./components/Landing.vue";
import Bio from "./components/Bio.vue";
import Shop from "./components/Shop.vue";
import Contact from "./components/Contact.vue";
import App from "./components/App.vue";
import "./assets/style.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",

  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: Landing,
      name: "landing",
      props: { order: 1 }
    },
    {
      path: "/bio",
      component: Bio,
      name: "bio",
      props: { order: 2 }
    },
    {
      path: "/shop",
      component: Shop,
      name: "shop",
      props: { order: 3 }
    },

    {
      path: "/contact",
      component: Contact,
      name: "contact",
      props: { order: 4 }
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
  console.log(from.matched[0].props);
  next();
});

let vm = new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    transitionName: ""
  },
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

and here is my `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="test"> // will soon be replaced by ":name="transitionName"
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// I don't know what I'm doing
export default {
  props: ["className"],

  data() {
    return {
      transition: this.className
    };
  }
};
</script>


<style>
.test-enter-active,
.test-leave-active {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.test-enter-active {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.test-enter,
.test-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

#Todo: Add missing classNames;
</style>
```

I would like to compare the two order props to know what transition to pick, but, since I'm really new to Vue, I'm struggling to retrieve them correctly, or maybe I'm just not doing anything good at all.

According to this link, props are meant to be passed in the url, which I don't want. Also, when I console log `from` from the `router.beforeEach` method (`to` doesn't seem to work, but I've heard about `nextTick()` ), I get to find my props but it can't find it with what I tested.

How can I solve my problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you may want to use `meta` instead of `props` the props are passed to the child component, but the meta is accessible by the route handler `beforeRouteUpdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of using `meta` parameter to determine which animation to use

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Home = {
  template: `
    <div class="home">
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
  `
};

const Parent = {
  data() {
    return {
      transitionName: "slide-left",
    };
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    this.transitionName = to.meta.animation;
    next();
  },
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      <h2>Parent</h2>
      {{transitionName}}
      <transition :name="transitionName">
        <router-view class="child-view"></router-view>
      </transition>
    </div>
  `
};

const Default = { template: '<div class="default">default</div>' };
const Foo = { template: '<div class="foo">foo</div>' };
const Bar = { template: '<div class="bar">bar</div>' };
const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home, td: 3, meta: {animation: 'slide-up'}, },
  {
    path: "/parent",
    component: Parent,
    td: 1,
    meta: {animation: 'slide-down'},
    children: [
      { path: "", component: Default, meta: {animation: 'slide-down'}},
      { path: "foo", component: Foo, meta: {animation: 'slide-right'}},
      { path: "bar", component: Bar, meta: {animation: 'slide-left'}}
    ]
  }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes
});

new Vue({
  router,
  template: `<div id="app">
      <h1>Transitions</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><router-link to="/">/</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/parent">/parent</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/parent/foo">/parent/foo</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/parent/bar">/parent/bar</router-link></li>
      </ul>
      <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <router-view class="view"></router-view>
      </transition>
    </div>`
}).$mount("#app");
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
/*   transition-property: opacity; */
/*   transition-timing-function: ease; */
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.1,1);
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
.view {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.child-view {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.1,1);
}
.slide-left-enter, .slide-right-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(30px, 0);
  transform: translate(30px, 0);
}
.slide-left-leave-active, .slide-right-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, 0);
  transform: translate(-30px, 0);
}
.slide-up-enter, .slide-down-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 30px);
  transform: translate(0, 30px);
}
.slide-up-leave-active, .slide-down-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -30p0);
  transform: translate(0, -30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/2.3.0/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer / comment, I couldn't test your code until now! That's exactly what I needed, now I just need to adapt it to my own project, thank you a lot!